# problem while deploying sinatra application on heroku

Tags: heroku

I am able to deploy my basic sinatra app on heroku but running it gives "APP CRASHES" error

## running "heroku logs" give the following error. I am using ruby1.9.1. dont know why this ruby1.8.7 shows in the backtrace. Please help

anmol@anmol-laptop:heroku$ heroku logs
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sinatra (LoadError)
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
 from ./main.rb:2
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
 from config.ru:1
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in`initialize'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `new'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in`map'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in`initialize'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in`instance_eval'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in`new'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1

==> dyno-3277552.log (crash) <==
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sinatra (LoadError)
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
 from ./main.rb:2
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
 from config.ru:1
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in`initialize'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `new'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in`map'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in`initialize'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in`instance_eval'
 from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in`new'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1

-----> Your application is requiring a file that it can't find.

```
   Most often this is due to missing gems, or it could be that you failed
   to commit the file to your repo.  See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for
   more information on managing gems.
```

## Examine the backtrace above this message to debug.

Comment: Do you have bundle without configured?

Answer (score 6):

create a file with a name ".gems" and include this line "sinatra".

by this way you are instructing to include sinatra gem

More information is here: http://docs.heroku.com/rack#sinatra

Comment: +1 for the link, although your inline advice is now outdated.